# Pydrake: Add primitive body (using Box helper function) to Multibody Plant for collision modelling? Multiple Multibody Plants?

Tags: drake

| drake 1.9.0 | python 3.7 | OS: ubuntu 20.04 | pycharm |

I have a Kuka arm welded to world that I'd like to use to knock around some primitive bodies (cubes, cylinders, etc.)

Based on [this][1] I am operating under the assumption that any and all models I'd like to interact and simulate contact dynamics for must belong to the same MultibodyPlant.
Is this assumption valid?

Adding additional ModelInstances to the same plant results in a larger number of controllable links for that plant. This implies that separate MultibodyPlants must be generated for every controllable sub-system to connect to Controller LeafSystems. (This is how the manipulation station appears to be set up.) Is this assumption also valid?

If so, I'm concerned about synchronization between the contact simulation timesteps and the timesteps used for individual controller-multibodyplant control. Is there guidance on this?

Lastly, is there a way I can use the Box shape class to add a primitive box directly to a MultiBody plant?
I've been investigating the AddRigidBody function but it needs a spatial inertia matrix that I would hope could be autogenerated for child classes of shape using some helper function.

Thanks
[1]: [Contact between two models causing IndexError: _Map_base::at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947778/contact-between-two-models-causing-indexerror-map-baseat)

Comment: My answer is incomplete; so I'm making this a comment:
1. Yep. Everything needs to be in the same plant for contact.
2. Control -- this is not my area of expertise and can't provide a ready answer right now.
3. Adding a box. You can use the [SpatialInertia::SolidBox()](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.tree.html?highlight=spatialinertia#pydrake.multibody.tree.UnitInertia_.UnitInertia_-float-.SolidBox) method to get the spatial inertia of a box.

Comment: If you already have a `pydrake::geometry::Box`, you can use [CalcSpatialInertia()](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.tree.html#pydrake.multibody.tree.CalcSpatialInertia) to get the spatial inertia directly from the `Box`.

Comment: Sounds good - last question: ' I'm concerned about synchronization between the contact simulation timesteps and the timesteps used for individual controller-multibodyplant control. Is there guidance on this?' Thanks @SeanCurtis

Answer (score 2):

> Based on [this][1] I am operating under the assumption that any and all models I'd like to interact and simulate contact dynamics for must belong to the same MultibodyPlant. Is this assumption valid?

Yes.

> Adding additional ModelInstances to the same plant results in a larger number of controllable links for that plant.

Yes, adding floating bodies to a plant will increase its number of positions (degrees of freedom).  So the full `q` vector will be both the robot positions and the free body positions.

> This implies that separate MultibodyPlants must be generated for every controllable sub-system to connect to Controller LeafSystems. (This is how the manipulation station appears to be set up.) Is this assumption also valid?

This part is not quite correct. For the actual dynamics simulation, everything should just be in one plant. We want all of the bodies to interact with each other.

In the `drake/examples/manipulation_station` code, it does also have a "controller plant" from `MakeIiwaControllerModel()` -- that "mini" plant only contains the robot without any other bodies to manipulate. However, that plant is only ever used to run the `InverseDynamicsController` to convert commanded positions into commanded torques. It is not used for resolving contact dynamics or any other manipulation-like activities.  But you're right for that "mini" plant, you would only add the robot and control the robot dofs, not any free bodies.

> Lastly, is there a way I can use the Box shape class to add a primitive box directly to a MultiBody plant?

In many cases the easiest way to add models is via the [Parser](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.parsing.html#pydrake.multibody.parsing.Parser) class. It supports several input formats (SDFormat, URDF, Mujoco, OBJ).

For trivial shapes with auto-computed inertia, sometimes [Mujoco](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/stable/XMLreference.html) is easiest. If you save this as `box.xml` and then `parser.AddModel("box.xml")`, it should add a box as a floating body:

```xml
<mujoco model="box">
  <worldbody>
    <body name="box" pos="0 0 1" euler="30 0 45">
      <geom name="box" type="box" size="0.1 0.2 0.3"/>
      <joint type="free" name="free"/>
    </body>
  </worldbody>
</mujoco>
```

Try running [model_visualizer](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.visualization.model_visualizer.html) on `box.xml` to preview it, before adding it to your plant.

See also Sean's replies to the original post, in case you'd like to compute the inertia from a parametric Box. Though for my taste, a python f-string of some XML like my above is easier than API calls.

Comment: Sounds good - last question: 'I'm concerned about synchronization between the contact simulation timesteps and the timesteps used for individual controller-multibodyplant control. Is there guidance on this?' Thanks

Comment: The "mini plant" used by the inverse dynamic controller is not timestepped (it's private to the controller) so there is no issue.